# how can we get all object properties of an ontology

Tags: owl, ontology, owl-api

I need to get all semantic relations between concepts of an ontology. So while I'm working on an OWL ontology ( People), I'm interested in object properties.
I use codes like the following one with `OBJECT_PROPERTY_DOMAIN` or `OBJECT_PROPERTY_RANGE`:

```
for (OWLClass cls : classes) {
            System.out.println("+: " + cls.getIRI().getFragment());

            System.out.println(" \tObject Property Domain");
            for (OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom op : ontology.getAxioms(AxiomType.OBJECT_PROPERTY_DOMAIN)) {                        
                    if (op.getDomain().equals(cls)) {   
                        for(OWLObjectProperty oop : op.getObjectPropertiesInSignature()){
                             System.out.println("\t\t +: " + oop.getIRI().getFragment());
                        }
                    }
                }
            
        }
```

But I need to get the whole relation, I mean the expression that links the domain with the range and the object property something like : *"Person drives car"*  exactly like in the image [image]

please if you have any idea help me; Thank you

Comment: You should start with the properties and retrieve domain and range, that's obviously more simple to achieve. The rest is pretty straithforward

Comment: Thank you for your help. I think to achieve my goal I need to use reasoners instead of treating just axioms ... while I'm looking for all semantic relations even those gotten by inference

Comment: And how does this make a difference? Then ask the reasoner for domains and ranges of each property instead of using the axioms from the ontology.

Comment: I'm not sure if that makes a difference. The problem is that I can't get all semantic relations... For example, the property "eats" has a domain which is "Animal". So, "Animal eats (some)Thing". But there is another semantic relation in the ontology which uses the property "eats" which is "dog eats bone". In that case, how can I get the second one... Because "dog" is defined in the owl file as a subclass of the restriction "eats some values from bone".

Comment: That's not the semantics of domain resp. range. And I don't understand how you would determine "bone" as the range. Domain and range are globally defined for each property. Anything else is contained in subclass/equivalent class axioms. In your question, you were only talking about domain and range. If you need more, then you have to use also the class axioms and check for those with a named class as subclass, e.g. something like "Dog SubClassOf eats some Thing"

Comment: You're right. In fact, my objective is getting all semantic relations determined by object properties (relations between classes). So, the expression "Dog eats some bone" must be taking into account too. In the picture, I have 19 relations that must be returned. While proposing a solution based only on domains and ranges it won't be enough to describe all semantic relations. I have to treat all cases domains, ranges and sub/equi axioms ...

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this point.

Comment: I wanna just ask if there is a way to do this practically. for example instead of verifying for each class her subclasses and equivalent classes if they contain a property; can I return directly those properties within subclasses and equivalent classes then looking for named class... but I think I can't get the other expression class: in the example "dog eats some bone" I mean by the other class:  'bone'